# Django ViewDoesNotExist at / Could not import Error

Tags: django

I am getting an error with my Django app on the production server (the dev server it works fine)
ViewDoesNotExist at /facebookLogin/
Could not import userinfo.views.newUniversity. View does not exist in module userinfo.views.

I did a little bit of reading and it seems like this usually stems from circular imports. I checked my imports and I don't think there are any circularities:

userinfo.views:

```
import json
import datetime
import random, urlparse, urllib, urllib2
from userinfo.models import UserInfo, University, LoginForm, UniversityForm, Organization, PotentialManager
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response, HttpResponse, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

events.views:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response, HttpResponse, redirect
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from events.models import Event, EventForm, Caterer, CommentForm, Advertisement, Comment
from userinfo.models import UserInfo, University, Organization
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from events.profinities import containsProfinities
from random import randint
```

But it's super curious to me because if I was getting this problem whenever it hit any `return redirect('/whatever/')`. But if I changed those to `from app.views import whatever` & `return whatever(request)` It fixes the problem. But in my facebookLogin code I need to call a redirect.

Also, my site has worked for months. This problem hasn't manifested itself until the last couple of days in which I haven't touched the server. Baffling.

The other weird thing is that I have taken out the NewUniversity module altogether. It's not even in my project anymore. I don't know why it is still trying to import it. I am baffled

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^facebookLogin', 'userinfo.views.facebookLogin', name='facebook login'),
    url(r'^selectUniversity/', 'userinfo.views.selectUniversity', name='select university'),
    url(r'^loginView/', 'userinfo.views.loginView', name='login'),
    url(r'^editProfile/', 'userinfo.views.editProfile', name='login'),
    url(r'^guestLogin/', 'userinfo.views.guestLogin', name='guest login'),
    url(r'^events/', 'events.views.eventList', name='event list'),
    url(r'^logout/', 'userinfo.views.logoutView', name='logout'),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^(?P<school>.*)/', 'events.views.schoolEvents', name='events'),
    url(r'^$', 'events.views.eventList', name='home'),
)
```

Comment: Please post your relevant `urls.py` files so we can see what the url router is trying to do here. Also, `return redirect('/whatever/')` and `return whatever()` are not equivalent (the former is most likely what you mean to do, and it goes through the `urls.py` code, so I suspect your problem is there).

Comment: Updated with URL's. I get the difference between the redirect and just calling another function. I think the error is deeper than this, because it works on my local machine, just on the server. & Even calling redirect to facebook.com I am getting this error, which is baffling..

Comment: Can you post your full stack trace with the error? Perhaps there's a `reverse` or a `url` template tag being called somewhere looking for the old view or something else that is a side effect of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Now I feel dumb. It was in fact a problem with urls.py. The ones on my server didn't get updated with the ones on my local machine. I found this by doing a grep search on "newUniversity". Some of the urls were able to work while others didn't just because of the order I think. I'm usually better than this. Thanks jonafato for being patient with me.